# substracting two rows in one column based on other columns values in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I am trying to work with a covid dataset. Below shows the tail of my COVID DF.

I need a new column (covid ['Daily_Confirmed']) that subtract the 'Confirmed' Columns in each row since this feature shows the aggregated data.

Two rows in the Confirmed column should be deducted if 'region', 'Population', and 'date' columns are the same.

This way we will have a number of daily confirmed cases for each region in the same DF.

|  | region | Population | date | Confirmed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10889 | Tipperary | 159553 | 2021-04-22 | 5719 |
| 10890 | Waterford | 116176 | 2021-04-22 | 5542 |
| 10891 | Westmeath | 116176 | 2021-04-10 | 3780 |

```
for i in range (1 ,len(covid)):
        if (covid['region'][i] == covid['region'][i-1]) and (covid['Population'][i] == covid['Population'][i-1]) and (covid['Population'][i] == covid['date'][i] == covid['date'][i-1]:
            covid ['Daily_Confirmed'] = covid['Confirmed'].loc[i] - covid['Confirmed'].loc[i-1]
covid.head()
```

Comment: `df.sort_values('date', ascending=False).groupby(['region', 'Population'])['Confirmed'].diff()` ?

Comment: @ScottBoston, Hi Many thanks for this. I face an issue that the deducted number displays in the wrong rows. I mean if the Confirmed cases for 05/03/2021 is 100 and a day before was 95, now the deducted number should be 5 and display in the row related to 05/03/2021 and not 04/03/2021 row.

Comment: Just reversing the sort order from @Scott Boston's answer should solve this I believe: `df.sort_values('date').groupby(['region', 'Population'])['Confirmed'].diff()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor edit to @Scott Boston's answer

```
df.sort_values('date').groupby(['region', 'Population'])['Confirmed'].diff()
```